# raise TesseractError(status, errors) pyocr.error.TesseractError: (-1073741819, '')

Tags: python-2.7

I got the following error when I use pyocr：

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "F:/workspace/work/project/image/imageword_extract/test_pyocr.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       print tools[0].image_to_string(enhance_image(image_path+'\timg1.jpg'),lang='chi_sim')
>   File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyocr\tesseract.py", line 358, in
>   image_to_string
>       raise TesseractError(status, errors) pyocr.error.TesseractError: (-1073741819, '')

There is no problem to identify the English, when to identify the Chinese reported the above error

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you have "chi_sim.traineddata" training file in tessdata directory, if not please place the file and then give a try. Good Luck!

Training File available at below link:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/4.00/chi_sim.traineddata